# Difference between selectors

Tags: jquery, css

I am confused between these two selector as they perform the same result. So I just want to why and we should use `>` selector

```
$(function(){
$('ul > li').addClass('red')
$('ul  li').addClass('red')
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>C</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They are completly different selectors... And no, they don't give same result. Anyway, that's so basic question i cannot believe you didn't find any info before posting this question...

Comment: Have you read [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have updated the question

Comment: I just copied the same thing. My question is something different

Comment: If you run it - you can see that they're not the same.

Comment: atleast google something before asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` is used to select the direct children of your elements.

For example:

```
<ul class="root">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
             <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

`$('ul.root > li').addClass('red')` will add class `red` to all of your `li` except `li` that nested inside another `ul` from above HTML markup.

```
<ul>
    <li class="red">a</li>
    <li class="red">b</li>
    <li class="red">
        <ul>
             <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="red">d</li>
</ul>
```

where as `$('ul.root li').addClass('red')` will apply class `red` to all of your `li` as long as your `li` is the children of `ul.root`

```
<ul>
    <li class="red">a</li>
    <li class="red">b</li>
    <li class="red">
        <ul>
             <li class="red">c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="red">d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="MasterContainer">
   <div>   <!-- Level 1 -->
      <div>   <!-- Level 2 -->
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>   <!-- Level 1 -->
      <div>   <!-- Level 2 -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Scenarios:

```
// Will add class 'red' to both Level 1 and Level 2 divs.
$('#MasterContainer div').addClass('red');   

// Will add class 'red' to only Level 1 divs.
$('#MasterContainer > div').addClass('red');

// Will add class 'red' to only Level 2 divs.
$('#MasterContainer > div > div').addClass('red');
```

To wrap it up, '>' is typically very useful when you want to target elements at a specific HTML/DOM level.